# Rails can't find the generator class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have some code that is using SyncEnumerator.  As you can see [here](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/SyncEnumerator.html), SyncEnumerator requires generator.rb.  To include this, the developer of this plugin has require 'generator'.  This worked on my previous Rails installation but is not working since I upgraded OS X and reinstalled Rails. Now when I try to install my gems, I get:

```
Macintosh:mls TAmoyal$ sudo rake gems:install
(in /Users/TAmoyal/Desktop/RoR_Projects/mls)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- generator

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Stack Trace:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require': no such file to load -- generator (MissingSourceFile)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/TAmoyal/Desktop/RoR_Projects/mls/vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/page_scraper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/TAmoyal/Desktop/RoR_Projects/mls/vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/aol.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/TAmoyal/Desktop/RoR_Projects/mls/vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook.rb:68:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/TAmoyal/Desktop/RoR_Projects/mls/vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook.rb:68:in `each'
    from /Users/TAmoyal/Desktop/RoR_Projects/mls/vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook.rb:68:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/TAmoyal/Desktop/RoR_Projects/mls/vendor/plugins/blackbook/init.rb:1:in `block in evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/plugin.rb:146:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/plugin.rb:146:in `block in evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/plugin.rb:142:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `block in load_plugins'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:348:in `load_plugins'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:163:in `process'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /Users/TAmoyal/Desktop/RoR_Projects/mls/config/environment.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/commands/server.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/server:3:in `require'
    from script/server:3:in `<main>'
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Rails. Both SyncEnumerator and Generator are part of the [Ruby Core Library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/SyncEnumerator.html). You should have both in Ruby 1.8.x.

Could you post the full exception trace?

**EDIT:**

In Ruby 1.9 the Generator library has been removed in favor of Fibers.
See [here](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2008/04/ruby-19-standar.html) and [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/08/ruby-1-9-fibers).

The library you are using is not compatible with Ruby 1.9. You can try to copy the Generator and SyncEnumerator files from Ruby 1.8.x, but I don't know whether this solution will work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I have Ruby 1.9.x.  Stack trace is posted

Comment: Generator has been removed from Ruby 1.9. See my edit on the original response for more details.

Answer (score 1):

in 1.9 there's Enumerator::Generator

or you might be able to get away with creating your own file
'generator'
that just does
Generator = Enumerator

GL.
-r

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with ruby 1.8 and found that my problem was that i was requiring 'generator' and that changing it to require 'generator.rb' fixed it.  I believe this was because of a conflict in rails with its own Generator class

Answer (score 0):

SyncEnumerator has moved to `rexml/syncenumerato`r in Ruby 1.9.x you can use it by doing `require 'rexml/syncenumerator'`